# Change SQL Query of an Annotation Class in an existing Annotation Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, annotation

I have an annotation feature class containing several annotation classes. There are SQL queries set on the annotation classes. They act as a definition query, determining which features are part of a certain annotation class.

An example would be `OBJTYP = '3A' OR OBJTYP = '3B' OR OBJTYP = '3C'`. The queries originate from the label settings on the layer which was used to create the annotation feature class.

I now want to change the SQL queries. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What are the SQL Queries doing?  Are these definition queries, or were these used to fill the annotation classes to start with?  Please provide some more detail, perhaps include what the sql strings are supposed to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change these and other properties of the annotation feature class in ArcCatalog. Just double click on the annotation feature class to open the properties and switch to the Annotation Classes tab.
Make sure there is no lock on the feature class, otherwise everything is grayed out. My feature class was being used in a map service, therefore it was locked permanently. That's why I got the impression that these properties can't be changed at all.

ESRI Support helped me out on this one.